# restFB creating reachandfrequencypred i don't see this class

Tags: java, facebook, restfb

So I'm trying to see how I can get and create reachandfrequencypred
in the marketing API ([creating method](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/reference/reach-frequency-prediction#Creating)). It gives you direction like this but I'm using the restFB api JAVA. If you look at the [RestFB docs](http://restfb.com/javadoc/) for the classes there is none for reachandrequencyprediction or anything about prediction

Comment: You should open an issue on Github. If you don't have a Github account, drop a line here and I'll do it, but then tracking is not that easy for you ;)

Comment: Thanks!!. 
I found out you can ask directly on facebook direct support so i just put it there. 
i will also make a comment in github

Answer (score 0):

The missing type is added with RestFB 1.45.0.

See here: https://github.com/restfb/restfb/issues/779